# Directory is not being recognized in Python

Tags: python, django, zip

I'm uploading a zipped folder that contains a folder of text files, but it's not detecting that the folder that is zipped up is a directory. I think it might have something to do with requiring an absolute path in the `os.path.isdir` call, but can't seem to figure out how to implement that.

```
            zipped = zipfile.ZipFile(request.FILES['content'])
            for libitem in zipped.namelist():
                if libitem.startswith('__MACOSX/'):
                    continue
                # If it's a directory, open it
                if os.path.isdir(libitem):
                    print "You have hit a directory in the zip folder -- we must open it before continuing"
                    for item in os.listdir(libitem):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you've uploaded is a single zip file which is simply a container for other files and directories.  All of the Python `os.path` functions operate on files on your local file system which means you must first extract the contents of your zip before you can use `os.path` or `os.listdir`.

Unfortunately it's not possible to determine from the `ZipFile` object whether an entry is for a file or directory.

A rewrite or your code which does an extract first may look something like this:

```
import tempfile

# Create a temporary directory into which we can extract zip contents.
tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
try:
    zipped = zipfile.ZipFile(request.FILES['content'])
    zipped.extractall(tmpdir)

    # Walk through the extracted directory structure doing what you
    # want with each file.
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(tmpdir):
        # Look into subdirectories?
        for dirname in dirnames:
            full_dir_path = os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)
            # Do stuff in this directory
        for filename in filenames:
            full_file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            # Do stuff with this file.
finally:
    # ... Clean up temporary diretory recursively here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually to make things handle relative paths etc when running scripts you'd want to use `os.path`.

It seems to me that you're reading from a Zipfile the items you've not actually unzipped it so why would you expect the file/dirs to exist?

Usually I'd `print os.getcwd()` to find out where I am and also use `os.path.join` to join with the root of the data directory, whether that is the same as the directory containing the script I can't tell.  Using something like `scriptdir =  os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`.

I'd expect you would have to do something like

```
libitempath = os.path.join(scriptdir, libitem)
if os.path.isdir(libitempath):
    ....
```

But I'm guessing at what you're doing as it's a little unclear for me.